# Undefined Function Call

Tags: php, function, class, oop

I am getting the following error:

> Call to undefined function convertTextFile()

How can I call that specific function?

Here's my code:

```
public function post_files()
{
    // $file = Input::file('file'); // your file upload input field in the form should be named 'file'
    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg","htm","html", "ppt","pptx","png","txt","pdf","doc","rtf","docx","xls","xlsx","bmp");

    if(isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']))
    {
        $i=0;
        foreach(Input::file('image') as $key => $file)
        { 
            $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["image"]["name"][$i]);
            $extension = end($temp); 
            $filename= $temp[0];
            $destinationPath = 'upload/'.$filename.'.'.$extension;
            $name=$filename.'.'.$extension; 

            if(in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
            {     
                if($_FILES["image"]["error"][$i] > 0)
                {
                    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["image"]["error"][$i] . "<br>";
                }

                $sql=Author::check_document_details_Call($name);
                $exist=$sql[0]->result;


                if($exist == "1")
                {
                    echo $filename." already exists.<br> ";
                }
                else
                { 
                    $uploadSuccess=move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"][$i],$destinationPath);

                    if( $uploadSuccess )
                    {
                        if($extension=='txt')
                        {
                            convertTextFile($destinationPath,"uploads/".$filename.".html");
                           $filename=$extension.".html";
                        }

                       $document_details=Response::json(DocumentProperty::insert_document_property_Call($name,$destinationPath));
                       echo "Update   ".$name."   successfully!!<br>";
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        return Response::json('error', 400);
                    }
                }
            }

            $i++;
        }
    }
}


function convertTextFile($inputFileName,$outputFileName)
{
    convertTxtToHtml($inputFileName,$outputFileName);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`$this->convertTextFile()` and again the same applies for the function inside it `convertTxtToHtml`.

Why dont you just call `$this->convertTxtToHtml()` directly from within the `post_files` function, why create a new function for a single line of code?

Answer (score 0):

If this is within a class like your `oop` tag suggests, you need to call the function using `$this->convertTextFile()`.

Your method should also have visibility properties depending on how it will be accessed. If it's only called from within that class give it a `private` visibility.